# Can't stop thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have these two methods for creating and stopping a thread. However the thread still keeps running, even after the first method is called. (I'm creating an object of the class and calling them from another class).

```
private Thread thread;

public void stopAlarm() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "stopAlarm called");
    sendAlarm = false;
    if (!thread.equals(null)) {
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public void triggerAlarm() {
    Runnable alarmTest = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (sendAlarm) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(sendAlarm));
            }
        }
    };
    thread = new Thread(Test);
    thread.start();
}
```

When stopAlarm is called the thread is always null, although it is called after triggerAlarm is called (thread is running).

Comment: make `sendAlarm` `volatile`

Comment: First of all you never ever write some thing like thread.equals(null) because if it is equal you will get an exception instead use thread == null second could you please post more of your code to make your problem more understandeble

Comment: didn't help, its still true, even after calling stopAlarm()

Comment: What is `sendAlarm`?  Please post *complete* question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by thread scope. Thread scope is created when you create a thread with same variables in the scope but you can't change these variables from outside world. Best practice for managing runnables in android is to use `Handler`.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable alarmTest = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(sendAlarm));
        handler.post(alarmTest, 5000); //wait 5 sec and run again
        //you can stop from outside
    }
};
```

after definitions, in order to start the runnable:

```
handler.post(alarmTest,0); //wait 0 ms and run
```

in order to stop the runnable:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(alarmTest);
```

EDIT: wait statement with loop

EDIT: Complete solution

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable alarmTest = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(sendAlarm));
        handler.post(alarmTest, 5000); //wait 5 sec and run again
        //you can stop from outside
    }
};

public void stopAlarm() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "stopAlarm called");
    handler.removeCallbacks(alarmTest);
}


public void triggerAlarm() {
    handler.post(alarmTest,0); //wait 0 ms and run
}
```

Comment: Works, but freezes my gui completely, making stopAlarm() useless.

Comment: Check if you post lots of alarmTest, there might be more than 1 instance

Comment: The method containing handler.post(alarmTest) is only called once.

Comment: Found the error, had a stry Thread.sleep(). However i'm now getting the error:

Comment: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: Created the handler in my GUI and passing it through, blocks the gui thread again :(.

Comment: It shouldn't block the gui. The runnable runs and dies for 5 sec. Try remove the handler.post() at the end of the run method, is gui blocked again?

Comment: I added the complete solution can you check again

Comment: Ended up doing it with a timer, since the code only runs once anyway after x seconds. Much simpler for what i wanted to do, but thanks for your effort :D.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your OS you may find making your thread [volatile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4) may fix this.

```
private volatile Thread thread;
```

However - there are better ways to do this. One very useful one is using a small (just one entry) `BlockingQueue` which is `poll`ed by the running thread.

```
// Use a BlockingQueue to signal the alarm to stop.
BlockingQueue<String> stop = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);

public void stopAlarm() {
    stop.add("Stop");
}


public void triggerAlarm() {
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            while (stop.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) == null) {
                // Stuff
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Clearly you will have to manage edge cases like where someone calls `stopAlarm` when no alarm is running.